# Criar uma função que roda dentro de uma coluna em python

Tags: python, funções, pandas

Eu venho de outra linguagem e não estou acostumada a criar funções em Python. Eu queria criar uma função que substituísse alguns caracteres especiais alemães. No entanto, quando eu vou passar essa função no dataframe, ela não retorna nada. O que eu estou fazendo errado?

```
import pandas as pd

def clean_german(x):
    return x.replace({'ä': 'ae', 'ö': 'oe', 'ü': 'ue', 'β': 'ss'}, regex = True, inplace = True)

# criando dataframe:
data = [['täm', 10], ['nök', 15], ['jüli', 14], ['saß', 22]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])

# print dataframe.
df
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
clean_german(df['Name'])
```

Aqui não me retorna nada. 
O que eu gostaria que retornasse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analisando o seu código, percebi que você não está chamando a função `clean_german` e passando o parâmetro necessário para realizar o `.replace()`, e mesmo, se você chamasse a função `clean_german`  vai ocorrer um erro `TypeError` por conta que o `.replace` (isso com os valores do `df['Name']`) não está recebendo palavras-chaves.

### Código

Existe diversas maneiras para substituir os caracteres alemães ([Regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), funções etc). Aqui vai uma maneira, simples utilizando [ord](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) do Python e o Lambda (*função anônima*).

#### Código sem a função para substituir os caracteres alemães

```
import pandas as pd

# criando dataframe:
data = [['täm', 10], ['nök', 15], ['jüli', 14], ['saß', 22]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])

# print dataframe.
df
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### Código com a função

```
import pandas as pd

# função para substituir os caracteres
caracteres = {ord('ä'):'ae', ord('ü'):'ue', ord('ö'):'oe', ord('ß'):'ss'}

# criando dataframe:
data = [['täm', 10], ['nök', 15], ['jüli', 14], ['saß', 22]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])

# reescrevendo a coluna 'Name' com a substituição dos caracteres alemães 
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.translate(caracteres)

# print dataframe.
df
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigada por essa explicação. É um jeito menos trabalhoso do que criar uma função =D

Answer (score -2):

Acabei na tentativa e erro solucionando:

```
def clean_german(df, x):
    df.replace({x: {'ä': 'ae', 'ö': 'oe', 'ü': 'ue', 'β': 'ss'}}, regex = True, inplace = True)
    return df
```